# Is it possible to defer overload resolution?

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

I was experimenting with overloads

```
int foo(int,int);
int foo(int);

int main() {           
    //decltype(foo) x;  // error: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved;
    decltype(foo(1)) f;      
}
```

I know that I cannot get a pointer to `foo` unless I pick one of the overloads, but I wonder why do overload sets have no type? Wouldnt it be natural to write

```
template <typename F>
void foofoo(F f,bool x) {
    if (x) f(1);
    else f(1,0);
}
```

and call it as `foofoo(foo,true);` ? I know that there are different ways to write something like that, but I specifically wonder about overload sets. Anyhow, my question is

**Is there anything I can do with an overload set before picking one of the overloads?**

In other words, is there some `magic` that would make the following `true` literally as is?

```
std::is_same_v< decltype( foo(1,1) ), magic<foo,int,int>::type >;
```

Or is this generally not possible, because `foo` is unresolved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are very few things you can do with the name of an overloaded function set that don't immediately require resolving to one specific function (or function template specialization).  But one context where many semantic checks get "delayed" in a way is inside a template.  And a generic lambda is a shortcut way of writing a template.  So one thing we can do is:

```
#include <utility>

#define WRAP_OVERLOADS(f) [](auto&& ...args) { \
    return f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }

int foo(int, int);
int foo(int);

int main() {
    auto f = WRAP_OVERLOADS(foo);
    f(1);
    f(2,3);
}
```

Though the preprocessor `#define` is required because there's no way to represent the name of the function to call to pass to a template. (A function pointer can be a template argument or can help deduce the type of a template function parameter, but then you're back to needing one specific overload to use the template.)

Comment: accepted your anwer but i have to admit that I am not completely convinced. I just found [this](http://manual.freeshell.org/libsigc++-2.0/reference/html/group__ptr__fun.html) where the second example has `sigc::slot<void, long> sl = sigc::ptr_fun1<int>(&foo);` with `foo` being overloaded. They also write "If the function pointer is to an overloaded type [...]" and it was sentences like that initially made me wonder if `foo` has a type at all

Comment: ups just after writing the comment I understood how `sigc::ptr_fun1<int>(&foo)` picks the right overload. Though I am still a bit confused about saying `foo` has a type before overload resolution has taken place

Comment: In fact `foo` does not have a type before overload resolution. But the name of an overloaded function can be used as a function pointer in certain cases where a compiler can determine the function type from context: [\[over.over\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.over)

Comment: "In fact foo does not have a type before overload resolution." this is exactly what I was looking for. Somehow I wasnt able to formulate the question in a more concise way before reading your answer and before i found said example